# Matplotlib 1.2 Error while plotting in Python 3.3

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot very simple stuff in `python 3.3` using `Matplotlib 1.3`. Below is the code which I am trying:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
plt.plot(x,y)
```

I am getting this message:

```
matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000000006711860
```

I just started with python and quite new in `python` world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.plot` returns a `lines.Line2D` object (since you're plotting a line).  I'm guessing you're working interactively, otherwise you wouldn't see that "message".

If you want the plot to actually show up, you need to add:

```
plt.show()
```

Comment: @User1551892 -- Nope.  from the interactive prompt, if a command returns something that isn't `None`, python will print it's string representation (`__repr__`)